# \xymatrix or other format

Tags: tikz-pgf, xymatrix

I want to draw the following:

[image]

Here is my try:

```
\begin{displaymath}
    \xymatrix{
        &P  \ar @{-}[ddl] \ar @{-}[dr]&\\
        & &P_1 \ar @{-}[d]\\
        P' \ar @{-}[dr] & & P_2 \ar @{-}[dl]\\
        &Q& }
    \end{displaymath}
```

but the output is different.

can you help please?

Comment: As always on this site you are more likely to get help if you post a full (but minimal) self contained document instead of just a sniplet like this. Then others can copy and test right away, here we have to invent a preamble etc, so a lot of people will pass on your question. This is very easy to draw in tikz, for xy you need 5 rows and 3 cols you only have 4 rows

Comment: many thanks. if i add rows, then the figure will be bigger, which i dont want. then how can i deal with it?

Comment: e the `xy` manual there are options to reduce row spacing'

Comment: thank you daleif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say "or other format". Maybe `tikz-cd` is an option?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em,row sep=1ex,every arrow/.append style={dash}]
 & \arrow[ddl] P \arrow[dr] & \\
 & & P_1\arrow[dd]\\
 P'\arrow[ddr] & & \\
 & & P_2\arrow[dl]\\
 & Q & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is an option tikz-cd :-) as request by the user.

Comment: Thank you veryyyyy  much.

Comment: `arrows=dash` is simpler.

Comment: @egreg Mille grazie! I agree, of course. It is just simpler for me to memorize the slightly longer keys as they immediately tell one what they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make five rows and to decrease the row spacing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix@R-1.5pc{
  & P \ar@{-}[ddl] \ar@{-}[dr] \\
  & & P_1 \ar@{-}[dd] \\
  P' \ar @{-}[ddr] \\
  & & P_2 \ar@{-}[dl] \\
  & Q
}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to increase the column spacing; the only change for the next picture is using

```
\xymatrix@R-1.5pc@C+0.5pc{
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.